# uninstall software center applications via bash

Tags: software-center, uninstall

Trying to uninstall an old version of Eclipse running:

```
sudo apt-get remove eclipse
```

I'm told the program isn't installed but I can see it in the software-center and run the program.

When I try to uninstall the program via software-center it looks like it's about to work but always fails. It seems like a password prompt is supposed to pop up but isn't for some reason. (Note: running i3-wm likely related)

Is there a way I can just uninstall the old version of eclipse via terminal?

Answer (score 2):

You can determine which package you have installed with `apt list --installed eclipse` Note that eclipse has many dependencies and suggested packages so removing eclipse via apt won't necessarily free up the ~300MB of disk space it took up when you installed it.

You might try `aptitude`or Synaptic to remove obsolete packages rather than blindly purging or removing packages with pattern matching.

`aptitude search ?obsolete` will give you a list of obsolete packages currently installed on your system allowing you to carefully pick and choose what to eliminate based on your knowledge of your system.

With the graphical package manager (Synaptic), (installable with the command `sudo apt install synaptic`) you can find the list of obsolete packages by clicking on the “Status” button and selecting “Installed (local or obsolete)”. You can then go through the list and decide for each package whether you want to keep it or not. Example below:

[image: syn-local]

Source:

https://raphaelhertzog.com/2011/02/07/debian-cleanup-tip-2-get-rid-of-obsolete-packages/

Comment: thanks for this answer, it didn't work in my case. I think the root of my problem was that eclipse was installed and there was a bin script to call it but it wasn't registered with apt. I posted my solution which was to find the folder location and delete it. Hopefully this doesn't cause any side effects.

Comment: I'm glad you got it sorted. Backups are the best way to avoid unintended consequences...

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem by deleting the folder `/usr/lib/eclipse/` there is also an associated bash script in the folder `/usr/bin/`.

In my case I didn't delete the `/usr/bin/eclipse` file, instead I just installed the latest eclipse and dragged the new eclipse folder into the old location.

Now when I run `eclipse` from terminal I get the new version.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove eclipse*
rm -r ~/.eclipse/
```

Comment: 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

If this app has been installed and after removal this app is not gone, try

> sudo apt autoremove

If this does not work try

> sudo apt remove --purge eclipse && sudo apt autoremove

Keep in mind this will remove all configurations done with eclipse.