# Not able to remove software from Software center

Tags: apt, software-center, uninstall, vmware

I am trying to uninstall `vmware-view` installed on my machine and I tried the following ways:

1) From Software Center:

Not sure why but I see that it is installed twice on my machine as you can see in the below screenshot.

I clicked the Remove button but nothing happened. I think I clicked may be 10 times all it does is opens another prompt asking if I really want to uninstall this and when I select Yes nothing happens after that and I still see listed here.

[image]

2) I tried to remove the same from terminal by typing the below command 
`sudo apt-get remove vmware-view` but it displays message that

> Unable to locate package vmware-view

What I am trying to do is re-install vmware view client as the current one is not working.

**Note:** I am on Ubuntu 16.10

Any help on this?

Comment: How did you install it in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation recently where software-center wouldn't uninstall a few programs. I recommend using the top answer first. [uninstall software center applications via bash](https://askubuntu.com/q/838827/135947)

But if that doesn't work, and the program is not registered with apt-get you can remove the files directly:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/<yourProgram>/
sudo rm /usr/bin/<yourProgram>
```

(I recommend looking in the folders first because the names might be slightly different from program name.)